# h5py: read_direct into a multidimensional numpy array returns ValueError

Tags: numpy, h5py

I am using read_direct to copy large vectors from an h5 file into a single 2D numpy array.  Large being millions of points.  read_direct is apparently faster than slicing notation because it avoids an intermediate copy.

My first attempt was:

```
def _harvest_data(grp: h5py.Group) -> np.array:
    data = np.zeros((64, grp['times'].shape[0]))
    index = 0
    for key, value in grp.items():
        if 'X' in key:
            value.read_direct(data, source_sel=None, dest_sel=np.s_[index, :])
            index += 1
    return data.mean(axis=0)
```

This returns an error, though:

> ValueError: 2 indexing arguments for 1 dimensions

The line given is the value.read_direct line.  What I don't understand is why it is giving me this error.  The data array is 2D, so giving it a 2D index seems perfectly sensible.  If I change to `dest_sel=np.s_[:]` every dataset will be copied into the first row of data, which is obviously not what I want.

A work around is to do the following:

```
def _harvest_data(grp: h5py.Group) -> np.array:
    data = np.zeros((64, grp['times'].shape[0]))
    index = 0
    for key, value in grp.items():
        if 'X' in key:
            value.read_direct(data[index, :], source_sel=None, dest_sel=None)
            index += 1
    return data.mean(axis=0)
```

This works, but I do not understand why the first attempt doesn't.

Working with kcw78's answer, I tried this

```
def _harvest_data(grp: h5py.Group) -> np.array:
    data = np.zeros((64, grp['times'].shape[0]))
    index = 0
    for key, value in grp.items():
        if 'X' in key:
            value.read_direct(data,
                              source_sel=None,
                              dest_sel=np.s_[index:index+1, :])
            index += 1
    return data
```

It gives the same KeyError as my first attempt, unfortunately.

Comment: With just `numpy`, `data[np.s_[0,:]] = 2` works fine, but I don't know what `h5py` is doing or what it's checking.   A full traceback might help, or one of us could study the `h5py` code.  The `h5py` examples use simpler 1d slices.  I haven't used this `read_direct`, so can't tell you from experience what are the limits.

Comment: Dumb question: why are you using `.read_direct()` when h5py supports numpy slice notation to read (and write) datasets? You can read a 64x1e6 array on a typical desktop system.

Comment: What is the shape of the value dataset (`value.shape)? From your code I assume 1-D. Correct? My example slices from 2-d to 2-d, and I didn't test a slice of None. Let me try that.

Comment: @Finncent Price, based on my updated tests with 1-d dataset and 2-d arrays, I suspect the problem isn't in your code. It may be the data -- a dataset that does not match the expected shape OR the number of datasets is > 64. Have you considered adding tests before the `value.read_direct()` line? Something like `if value.shape == (grp['times'].shape[0],) and index < 64:`. Also, you can use `enumerate()` to increment `index`, like this `for index, (key, value) in enumerate(grp.items()):`. Good luck. Hope you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: Answer updated May-27-2022 to include an example that reads from multiple 1-d datasets to a 2-d array (more closely mimics OP's workflow).

For reference, I am using `h5py.__version__`  `'3.3.0'`

A note in the numpy documentation for `np.s_` caught my eye. It says:

```
index_exp: Predefined instance that always returns a tuple: 
index_exp = IndexExpression(maketuple=True).

s_: Predefined instance without tuple conversion: 
s_ = IndexExpression(maketuple=False).
```

So, initially I thought you need to use `np.index_exp` instead of `np.s_` to get always slice tuples for h5py. However, a little testing shows it's slightly more complicated. I can't explain the underlying numpy code...but this will lead to a solution.

```
In [4]: np.s_[:,5]
Out[4]: (slice(None, None, None), 5)

In [5]: np.index_exp[:,5]
Out[5]: (slice(None, None, None), 5)

In [6]: np.s_[:,5:6]
Out[6]: (slice(None, None, None), slice(5, 6, None))
```

This is a new example to demonstrate reading from a 1-d dataset (`shape=(10,)`) to a 2-d array (`shape=(5,10)`). It reads values from 2 different datasets to first and last rows of the array. It uses None for source slice. Three different ways of specifying destination slice were tested. All 3 work.

```
with h5py.File('h5py_example_1d.h5','w') as h5f:
    arr_in = np.arange(10)
    # Create 5 1-d datasets with shape (10,)
    for i in range(5):
        h5f.create_dataset(f'dset_{i}', data=(arr_in+10.*i))

    arr_outr = np.zeros((5,10))
    # Read entire 'dset_0' dataset to 1st row of the array
    arr_outr[0,:] = h5f['dset_0'] # Read entire dataset, don't need to slice
    print(arr_outr)

    source = None
    destin = np.s_[4:5,:] # dest = np.s_[4:5,] np.s_[4,] also work
    print(f'source: {source}')
    print(f'dest: {destin}')
    # Read entire 'dset_4' dataset to 5th row of the array
    h5f['dset_4'].read_direct(arr_outr, source, destin)
    print(arr_outr)
```

This is the previous example that reads from a 2-D dataset to a 2-D array (both shape=100x100).

```
with h5py.File('read_direct_example.h5','w') as h5f:
    arr_in = np.arange(10*10).reshape(10,10)
    dset = h5f.create_dataset("dset", data=arr_in)
    arr_out = np.zeros((10,10))

    source = np.s_[:,5:6]
    dest = np.s_[:,0:1]
    print(f'source: {source}')
    print(f'dest: {dest}')

    arr_out[dest] = dset[source]
    print(arr_out)

    dest   = np.s_[:,9:10]
    print(f'dest: {dest}')
    dset.read_direct(arr_out, source, dest)
    print(arr_out)
```

Output of `arr_out` from both methods: (1) read the dataset with slice notation, and (2) using `read_direct()` with slices from `np.s_`)

```
[[ 5.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  5.]
 [15.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 15.]
 [25.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 25.]
 [35.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 35.]
 [45.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 45.]
 [55.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 55.]
 [65.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 65.]
 [75.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 75.]
 [85.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 85.]
 [95.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 95.]]
```